# Find the time it takes for the server with a websocket connection to send messages to client

Tags: timestamp, ping

from my understanding ping is how long it takes to send and then receive a message from the server. I have a server that's constantly sending values to clients. Is there a way to determine how long that took? I was thinking of sending a timestamp of when the server sends the message, then subtract that from a timestamp on the client? Is that reliable?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a timestamp with machine A, that timestamp will be the local time currently set on machine A (assuming no 3rd party service). When you compare this timestamp against the time on machine B you will see the difference.

However, consider the scenario where machine B is not exactly in sync with machine A, time calculated time won't be the real time. Using PTP one can get machine A and B within very good sync (provided a good network connection), or you could use NTP to sync both machines with the NTP pool.

With a confidence of the known discrepancy between A and B you can calculate time range that the message actually took to travel.

This is relevant at the millisecond level.